# Piano keyboard connects to Qsynth but no sound Linux

Tags: linux, audio, midi

I'm running Mint 18.3 Mate on an Intel i5-8600K desktop. I do not have a sound card or speakers. I have a Sennheiser headset that works fine when I listen to something off the web like youtube.

I have a USB piano keyboard and sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I'm using QjackCtl and Qsynth.

When I push a key on the piano, the green light in the lower left corner of Qsynth lights in unison.

In Qsynth, if I open Channels and push a key on the piano, the green light next to Yamaha Grand Piano lights. I do have two soundfont files loaded.

It has worked fine. Then it stops working. I have been searching a lot; what I've found says it should work, as far as I can tell.

[image: Jack audio connections]

[image: Jack alsa connections]

[image: Qsynth settings]

[image: aplay -l]

Comment: "Then it stops working." When? What changed?

Comment: I'd have a clue if I could answer. Nothing I know of. Clearly something is different.

Comment: Do other sounds still work?

Comment: Yes. I have in the past had trouble with Mint losing track of my headset. When the piano doesn't work (all the time now), I check Youtube or something and the headset always works.

Comment: Changing QSynth > Setup > Audio > Audio Driver > pulseaudio instead of alsa fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

Possibly I experienced the same issue as you. I now have it working again. It seems, once it starts working with certain settings, it seems to keep working from then on. Unfortunately I don't have a full answer on why that might be.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and Fluidsynth 1.1.9. The technique I used was to go into Fluidsynth (i.e. the command-line tool), play with the settings til it works, and then go back into QSynth and set the same setting values.

What worked for me was:

```
audio.driver=alsa
audio.alsa.device=pulse   [I have never got any output by going directly to alsa devices. I'm not sure why that is. I haven't tried jack, so you may need to experiment.]
synth.gain=10.0    [The default of 0.2 is inaudible on my system]
audio.output-channels=1
audio.sample-rate=22050.0
audio.sample-format=16bits
```

Once it was working in QSynth with these settings, I was able to return some of them back to their default values.

Comment: This works great. It was either setting audio driver to alsa or audio alsa device to pulse, or both. Now I don't need jack. Thanks very much. I must go make notes (both ways)..

Comment: OK, slight change. I do need to start jack for the piano to connect to Qsynth. Huge improvement over no sound.

Comment: How can you set `synth.gain` to 10 in Qsynth? By pressing the Setup button and going to the Settings tab, I can see the value 0.2 but cannot change it.